# RDLC line chart report to compare each item from different departments and 3 different time period

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, rdlc

I want to create RDLC line chart report to compare
- 1 item for many departments in 3 different periods.

What data field should I retrieve from database? I used below Query but that's not enough for chart.

```
SELECT  d.DepartmentName,
        SUM(CASE  WHEN r.Date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-31' THEN ri.RequiredQty ELSE 0 END) FirstMonth,
        SUM(CASE  WHEN r.Date BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-30' THEN ri.RequiredQty ELSE 0 END) SecondMonth,
        SUM(CASE  WHEN r.Date BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-31' THEN ri.RequiredQty ELSE 0 END) ThirdMonth
FROM    RequisitionItem ri, Requisition r, [User] u, Department d
WHERE   ri.RequisitionID = r.RequisitionID 
AND     r.UserID = u.UserID
AND     u.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
AND     ri.ItemID = 'C001'
AND     d.DepartmentID IN ( 'BIOL' , 'COMM', 'BIZL', 'CPSC')
GROUP BY d.DepartmentName
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to get data to generate your chart.
Each row of your select should contain 3 informations

- **Series** information in your case the department
- **X Axis** data that, I imagine, should be the time period
- **Y Axis** data that is the required quantity

So your query should loook like something like this

```
        SELECT  d.DepartmentName, --series field
            LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, r.Date,112),6) Period, --X Axis Values
            SUM(ri.RequiredQty) Quantity, --Y axis values
        FROM    RequisitionItem ri, Requisition r, [User] u, Department d
        WHERE   ri.RequisitionID = r.RequisitionID 
        AND     r.UserID = u.UserID
        AND     u.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
        AND     ri.ItemID = 'C001'
        AND     d.DepartmentID IN ( 'BIOL' , 'COMM', 'BIZL', 'CPSC')
        GROUP BY d.DepartmentName, LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, r.Date,112),6)
```

Info: this instruction `LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, r.Date,112),6)` is used to transform your date field in a YYYYMM field so that the group by groups department and month together.